# Does Direct Routing Calls API support filter?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to know does [getDirectRoutingCalls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-getdirectroutingcalls?view=graph-rest-beta) API support filter?

I have done the below tests in POSTMAN

**Test1:**

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/callRecords/getDirectRoutingCalls(fromDateTime=2021-05-06T01:48:48.7950838Z,toDateTime=2021-05-06T14:48:48.7950838Z)

```
@odata.count = 350
```

**Test2:**

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/callRecords/getDirectRoutingCalls(fromDateTime=2021-05-06T01:48:48.7950838Z,toDateTime=2021-05-06T14:48:48.7950838Z)?$filter=userId in ('user-id-of-azure-user')

```
@odata.count = 350
```

**Test3:**

[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/callRecords/getDirectRoutingCalls(fromDateTime=2021-05-06T01:48:48.7950838Z,toDateTime=2021-05-06T14:48:48.7950838Z)?$filter=startsWith(userDisplayName,'Owen')](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/callRecords/getDirectRoutingCalls(fromDateTime=2021-05-06T01:48:48.7950838Z,toDateTime=2021-05-06T14:48:48.7950838Z)?$filter=startsWith(userDisplayName,%27Owen%27))

```
@odata.count = 350
```

`@odata.count` was same in each test case.

Am i doing something wrong or API itself doesn't support filtering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently filtering is not supported in get Direct routing call API. Microsoft will always focus on customer’s feedback and experience, some new features would be added to the services based on customers' feedback in the future, we also recommend you give your new idea in Teams [UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) here, if this needs to be consider as a future request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.If you don't mind can you please provide any official reference that it is not supported?

Comment: If filter query is supported then it would have been mentioned in documentation stating that Optional Query Parameter. Please check this  example [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters) which support filter query parameter.